# Can't get VPN checker working with JSON api

Tags: python, json, api

I'm coding a VPN checker in python, and I can't get it working with the JSON api as it gives an error:

```
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

My code:

```
import requests
import threading
from requests import get
import urllib.request
import json
import colorama
from colorama import Fore
import os
colorama.init()

with urllib.request.urlopen(f"https://vpnapi.io/api/{ip}?key=apikey") as url: data = json.dumps(url.read().decode())

    vpn=data["security":"vpn"]
    proxy=data["'security":"proxy"]
    tor=data["security":"tor"]
    relay=data["security":"relay"]

    print(Fore.RED + f"\nVPN:" , Fore.WHITE + f"{vpn}")
    print(Fore.RED + f"\Proxy:" , Fore.WHITE + f"{proxy}")
    print(Fore.RED + f"\Tor:" , Fore.WHITE + f"{tor}")
    print(Fore.RED + f"\Relay:" , Fore.WHITE + f"{relay}")
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be in a new line ```data = json.dumps(url.read().decode())```  ?

Comment: it doesn't matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The returned data in your code is as a string and is not easily workable. Consider using the requests module for these type of API request applications.

```py
import colorama
import requests
from colorama import Fore

colorama.init()
api_key = "xxxx"
ip_address = "x.x.x.x"
url = f"https://vpnapi.io/api/{ip_address}?key={api_key}"
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.json()

vpn = data["security"]["vpn"]
proxy = data["security"]["proxy"]
tor = data["security"]["tor"]
relay = data["security"]["relay"]

print(Fore.RED + f"\nVPN:", Fore.WHITE + f"{vpn}")
print(Fore.RED + f"\nProxy:", Fore.WHITE + f"{proxy}")
print(Fore.RED + f"\nTor:", Fore.WHITE + f"{tor}")
print(Fore.RED + f"\nRelay:", Fore.WHITE + f"{relay}")
```

Comment: Please mark it as the accepted answer and upvote it if it helped you